# Prove that exist $e_1,\dots,e_n\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $|e_1z_1+{\dots}+e_nz_n|\le\sqrt2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

> Let $z_1,\dots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_p|\le1$ for every $p\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Prove that exist $e_1,\dots,e_n\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $|e_1z_1+{\dots}+e_nz_n|\le\sqrt2$.

I have firstly tried using induction. For $n=1$ I have $|e_1z_1|=|z_1|\le1\le2$, so it is true. Then I supposed that $|L|\le\sqrt2$ where $L=e_1z_1+{\dots}+e_kz_k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N},k\le n$. Then I tried to prove that it is true for $k+1$. But then I realized that it is impossible for any $z_{k+1}$ if I do not change values of $e_1,\dots,e_k$ because $|z_p|\le1$, but $|L|\le\sqrt2$. My second attempt is to write numbers $z_1,\dots,z_n$ in trigonometric form. Let $|z_p|=r_p$ and $\arg(z_p)=a_p$. Then I need to prove that
$$\sqrt{(e_1r_1\cos a_1+{\dots}+e_nr_n\cos a_n)^2+(e_1r_1\sin b_1+{\dots}+e_nr_n\sin b_n)^2}\le\sqrt2$$
but I do not know how it can help me to prove main inequality. What is the easiest way to prove it?

Comment: It is not $|e_1z_1+\cdots e_nz_n| \le 1$ ? It seems easier to prove.

Comment: @EmilioNovati. Let $n=2,z_1=1,z_2=i$, you will see that $|e_1z_1+e_2z_2|=\sqrt2$ for any $e_1,e_2$.

Comment: Sorry! it's time to go to sleep for me !

Comment: Is this a problem from Alon & Spencer "The Probabilistic Method"?  I'm certain I've seen this problem (and solution) before, but it isn't coming to me right off hand--can't recall the solution at the moment, but I can look through my coursework when I am home (if this does come from the text).

Comment: @TravisJ. My friend gave me this problem, I do not know what is its source.

Comment: [Results and references about generalizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1467610/71850).

Comment: See the solution by mavropevna [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h386586p2146775)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial Result:

First divide the unit disk into equal sectors as shown below.

[image: sectors]

Notice that adding two vectors from opposing sectors results in a vector also in the unit circle. Since we can choose whether a vector is in a sector or its opposite (by possibly multiplying by $-1$), we can reduce the problem to the case $n=3$ (where each vector lies in a different colored area).

Answer (score 6):

Peter Woolfitt's answer basically solves the problem. As he explains, we can reduce to the case $n=3$, where $\arg(z_1)$, $\arg(z_2)$ and $\arg(z_3)$ lie in $[0, \pi/3]$, $[2 \pi/3, \pi]$ and $[4 \pi/3,5 \pi/3]$ respectively. But, if $w$ and $z$ are in the unit disc and $2 \pi/3 \leq \arg(w) - \arg(z) \leq \pi$, then $w+z$ is in the unit circle. This will apply for one of the three pairs $(z_1, z_2)$, $(z_2, z_3)$ and $(z_3, z_1)$ so we reduce to $n=2$.

Possibly replacing $z_2$ by $-z_2$, we can assume that $z_1$ and $z_2$ make an obtuse angle with each other. Then $|z_1+z_2| \leq \sqrt{2}$, as desired.