# Given $v_i∈B^n$, bounding $\sum b_iv_i$ for $b_i= \pm 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, vectors

Let $(v_i)_{i∈ℕ}$ be a vector sequence. Say $(v_i)$ is *boundable (under $M$)* if there exists a sequence $(b_i)_{i∈ℕ}$ taking values in $\{-1,1\}$ such that $(|\sum^N_i b_iv_i|)_{N∈ℕ}$ is bounded (under $M$). If $(v_i)$ takes values in the unit ball $B^n⊆ℝ^n$, does it follow $(v_i)$ is boundable?

With the definition formulated analogously for finite sequences, I see I can utilize the (weak) Konig's lemma to show that a vector sequence is boundable under $M$ if and only if all its finite starting sequences are boundable under $M$. As such, it follows that if every such vector sequence is boundable, then there is a minimal such $α_n$ such that every vector sequence is boundable under $α_n$ (for example, $α_1=1$). Based on some randomized computations of mine it appears the hypothesis holds for $n=2$ and $1.6≤α_2≤1.7$, however I'm not sure how to continue.

**Edit:** It appears actually that should the hypothesis be true, then $α_2 ≥ \sqrt{3}$. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR1UL.png) diagram indicates how to construct a finite sequence unboundable under $r$ when $r < \sqrt{3}$: Start with the resultant vector $w_1$ (initial $v_1=(1,0)$) of magnitude $1$ or greater; choose the next vector $w_2$ such that $|w_1+w_2| > r$ yet the angle between $w_1,w_2$ is less than $2π/3$. Then $|w_1-w_2| > |w_1|$ and we can repeat the process with resultant vector $w_1-w_2$ to at least constantly greater effect each time. (Note the mirror situation of $b_1=-1$ is taken care of by symmetry)

Comment: The Euclidean norm can be replaced by any other, in particular by the maximum norm $\|v\|_\infty$. This reduces the $n$-dimensional problem to simultaneously bounding $n$ scalar sequences. Still no idea about which way it goes.

Comment: Is the $M$ a function of $N$? or does it need to be a constant?

Comment: If the $M$ can be a function of $N$ (which I sort of doubt after re-reading this) then you could use results like those for the Littlewood-Offord problem (specifically Kleitman's extension).  The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Offord_problem) page is fairly sparse on this, but if it looks like the right direction I can provide some additional details for you.

Comment: @Mice Elf: I've considered how the maximum norm might make this a less complicated problem (it sure does wonders in topological housekeeping), but I think the typical Euclidean norm might turn out more manageable as the $ε$-balls are more symmetric. I've also some proof that if the hypothesis is true for $n=2$, then in fact $\sqrt{3} ≤ α_2$; updating soon. TravisJ: Thanks for the reference. The $M$ may be (actually, must be) dependent on $n$, but not on $N$.

Comment: well it's quite easy to show that $\alpha_n < \sqrt n$ is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [$K_2$, p.22], $\alpha_2=\sqrt{3}$, $\alpha_n\le n$, and the problem if $\sup\frac{\alpha_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is finite is open. In [B] is proved that $\alpha_n(N)\le C_1\sqrt{n} + C_2\log N$ and is considered the counterpart of the problem for  the maximum norm $\|v\|_\infty$.

*References*

[B] Wojciech Banaszczyk, *[On series of signed vectors and their rearrangements](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262367930_On_series_of_signed_vectors_and_their_rearrangements)*, Random Struct. Algorithms **40**:3 (2012), 301-316.

[$K_1$] Vladimir Kadets, *[Review of [B]](http://mirrors.library.cornell.edu/ZMATH/msc/en/zmath/search/?q=an:06034902&type=pdf&format=complete)*,  Zbl 1250.46011.

[$K_2$] Vladimir Kadets, *[Rearrangements of series in Banach spaces: A short survey](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244280541_Rearrangements_of_series_in_Banach_spaces_A_short_survey)*, Palermo, July 2013.

Comment: Ah, yes, perfect. Just what could be asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a proof showing that $\alpha_2 \le \sqrt 3$.

We choose the signs one at a time as we look at the sequence, except that we allow ourselve to leave *one* sign undecided somewhere.

So at each step, we are either at one single point, or at two points at a distance at most $2$ from each other. We are given the next step $v_i$ and we have to decide what to do with them.

The following procedure should work :

Always try to go for one single point $P$ where $|P| \le 1$.
If that's impossible, we can go for two points $P,Q$ where $|P+Q| \le 2$. Either by splitting from the previous point ; by translating the previous two points and keeping the midle point in the circle of radius $1$ ; or by moving $P$ and $Q$ in opposite directions, keeping their distance small and not moving the middle point.

The farthest point we can get from a pair of point configuration is when the middle point is at $(1,0)$ and the two points are a small perturbation of $(1 \pm 1/2, \pm \sqrt 3/2)$, one of which is at distance $\sqrt 3$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my misuderstanding of the question, see the second Feryll's comment below.

---

According to Wojciech Banaszczyk [B1], S. Sevastyanov [S] and, independently I. Bárány (unpublished) proved that $\alpha_n=\sqrt{n}$. Also there is a lot of the generalizations of this inequality for different norms, see, for instance, the references.

*References*

[B1] Wojciech Banaszczyk, *[A Beck-Fiala-type Theorem for Euclidean Norms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669813800340)*, Europ. J . Combinatorics **11** (1990), 497-500.

[B2] Wojciech Banaszczyk, *[Balancing vectors and convex bodies](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-smv106i1p93bwm)*, Studia mathematica, **106** (1993), 93-100.

[G] Apostolos A. Giannopoulos,  *[On some vector balancing problems](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-smv122i3p225bwm)*, Studia mathematica, **122**:3 (1997), 225-234.

[S] S. V. Sevastyanov, *[On the approximate solution of the problem of calendar planning](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6_fgIk7Y03yazRUYlZXYktJVU0/edit)*, Upravlyaemye Systemy, **20** (1980), 49–63 (in Russian).

Comment: Haven't read the papers, but this already can't be; try bounding the beginning of the sequence (1,0), (0.14, 0.99), (0.75, 0.65)... You'll see it already can't fit into a ball of radius root 2. Nonetheless, I'll check out the references.

Comment: Yes, the first and third references (at least according to their abstracts) only concern the problem of finding binary coefficients for minimizing the distance of the whole sum, whereas with mine, each partial sequence also needs to be bounded. The second reference concerns finding the bound in the opposite direction, but which still doesn't disprove the hypothesis here. I would actually love to read the fourth seeing as I've been learning Russian, but так и не нашёл.

Comment: @Feryll I edited in a link to that paper, taking it from [this page at author's institute](http://math.nsc.ru/~wwwdoor/index.php/members/show_publications/14).