# Estimating quality of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, projection

Suppose we are given a vector $v$ and vectors $\mu_i$:

$v = \mu_1+\mu_2+...+\mu_m$, where $\mu_i \in R^n$, all $\mu_i$ are of unit length.

Oracle will give me $k$ vectors $\mu_{j_1}, \mu_{j_2},...\mu_{j_k}$ from the original set such that when I project $v$ onto subspace spanned by these vectors the length of the projection is highest possible. In other words, from the set of all combinations of $k$ vectors from $[\mu_1,...\mu_n]$ the $[\mu_{j_1}, \mu_{j_2},...\mu_{j_k}]$ give highest length of projection. Lets denote by $v_{\text{proj}}$ projection of $v$ onto $[\mu_{j_1}, \mu_{j_2},...\mu_{j_k}]$

I want to estimate quality of projection before oracle gives me this $k$ vectors. **I want to give upper bound on** $||v - v_{\text{proj}}|| $

As far as I understood it is very difficult to obtain these $k$ vectors by myself. However, I know  that for any two vectors $\mu_i, \mu_j$, $||\mu_i-\mu_j|| \leq \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is  a given positive number.

Small values of $\alpha$ will tell me that all $\mu_i$ are close to each other and heading towards same direction. I would suspect then that projection will be good, and its length will be close to the length of original vector. How can I use this to give an upper bound $||v - v_{\text{proj}}|| $?

**My attempts**:

Without loss of generality lets assume that $k$ optimal vectors are first $k$ vectors in the list, i.e $\mu_1,\mu_2,...\mu_k$. Lets denote by $P$ projection operator on the space spanned by $\mu_1,\mu_2,...\mu_k$.

$\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\|  = \|v - P(v)\| = \|v - P(\mu_1+\mu_2+...+\mu_m)\| = $

$\|v - P(\mu_1) - P(\mu_2) - ... - P(\mu_m)\| = $

$ \| v - \mu_1 - \mu_2 - ... - \mu_k - P(\mu_{k+1}) - P(\mu_{k+2}) - ... - P(\mu_m)\| = $

$\|\mu_{k+1} - P(\mu_{k+1}) + \mu_{k+2} - P(\mu_{k+2}) + ... + \mu_{m} - P(\mu_{m})\|$

$\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\| \leq \|\mu_{k+1} - P(\mu_{k+1})\| + \|\mu_{k+2} - P(\mu_{k+2}) + ... + \|\mu_{m} - P(\mu_{m})\|$

$\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\| \leq (m-k)\alpha$

So in order to make $\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\| \leq \epsilon$, we need $k \geq \frac{m\alpha - \epsilon}{\alpha}$

**I am not satisfied with this result because $k$ grows linearly with $m$**. I want it to grow much slower, something like $\log(m)$. My goal is to show that under some constraints on $\mu_i$, we need only approximately $\log(m)$ vectors to approximate $v$.

I think the bound can be improved substantially. First Cauchy inequality isn't very tight and second, I used $|\mu_{k+1} - P(\mu_{k+1})\| \leq \alpha$ which is also very loose.

**I am open for additional constraints on $\mu_1,...\mu_m$ to achieve logarithmic growth**

As Alex Ravsky has noted, we also need a constraint on $\alpha$ in order to achieve logarithmic growth. Assume that $m$ $\leq n$, $\mu_i$ is th $i$-th standard ort of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$. Then $\|v -  v_{\text{proj}}\| = \sqrt{m-k}$

Comment: @AlexRavsky Indeed. added your  comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is negative. Indeed, assume that $m\leq n-1$, $\alpha\le \sqrt{2}$ and for each $i\le m$, $\mu_i=\sqrt{1-\tfrac{\alpha^2}{2}}e_{m+1}+\tfrac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}e_i$, where for each $j$, $e_j$ is $i$-th standard ort of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is its $i$-th coordinate is $1$ and other coordinates are $0$).

Let $\mu_{j_1}, \mu_{j_2},...\mu_{j_k}$ be any $k$ vectors from the original set and $v_{\text{proj}}=\sum \lambda_i \mu_{j_i}$. 
Then 
$$\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\|^2=
\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right)\left(\sum_i \lambda_i-m\right)^2+\sum_i  \frac{\alpha^2}{2}(\lambda_i-1)^2+(m-k) \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\ge$$ $$ (m-k) \frac{\alpha^2}{2}.$$

We can improve this  lower bound as follows.

Put $\beta=\tfrac{\alpha^2}{2}\le 1$, $\Lambda_1=\sum_i\lambda_i$ and $\Lambda_2=\sum_i\lambda_i^2$. Remark that by the inequality between quadratic and arithmetic means, $\Lambda_2\ge \tfrac{\Lambda_1^2}{k}$. Then

$$\|v - v_{\text{proj}}\|^2=
\left(1-\beta\right)\left(\sum_i \lambda_i-m\right)^2+\sum_i  \beta(\lambda_i-1)^2+(m-k) \beta\ge $$
$$\left(1-\beta\right)(\Lambda_1^2-2m\Lambda_1)+ \beta\left(\frac{\Lambda_1^2}{k}-2\Lambda_1 \right)+m^2\left(1-\beta\right) +m\beta=$$
$$\left(1-\beta+\frac{\beta}{k}\right)\Lambda_1^2-2(\beta+m(1-\beta))\Lambda_1+m^2\left(1-\beta\right) +m\beta=$$
$$\left(\sqrt{1-\beta+\frac{\beta}{k}}\Lambda_1-\frac{\beta+m(1-\beta)}{\sqrt{1-\beta+\frac{\beta}{k}}}\right)^2- \frac{(\beta+m(1-\beta))^2}{1-\beta+\frac{\beta}{k}} +m^2\left(1-\beta\right) +m\beta\ge $$
$$-\frac{(\beta+m(1-\beta))^2}{1-\beta+\frac{\beta}{k}} +m^2\left(1-\beta\right) +m\beta=$$
$$\frac{1}{k-k\beta+\beta}(-k(\beta+m(1-\beta))^2 +( k-k\beta+\beta)(m^2 (1-\beta) +m\beta)=$$
$$ (m-k) \beta \frac{m-m\beta+\beta}{k-k\beta+\beta}.$$

On the other hand,  we  can obtain an upper bound for $\|v -  v_{\text{proj}}\|$ based on the following balancing sum

**Lemma** (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463017/given-v-i%e2%88%88bn-bounding-sum-b-iv-i-for-b-i-pm-1/1467610#1467610) answer for references) For any sequence $\{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_t\}$ of vectors of $\Bbb R^n$ of unit length there exists a sequence $\{\varepsilon_1,\dots, \varepsilon_t\}$ such that $\|\sum_{i=1}^t \varepsilon_i\nu_i\|\le\sqrt{n}$.

Now we inductively construct a sequence $\{v_s\}$ of vectors in $\Bbb R^d$ and a decreasing sequence $\{A_s\}$ of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ as follows. Put $A_0=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Given $A_s$, put $v_s=\sum_{i\in A_s} \mu_i$. In particular, $v_0=v$. By Lemma,  there exists a sequence $\{\varepsilon_i: i\in A_s\}$ such that $\|\sum_{i\in A_s} \varepsilon_i\mu_i\|\le\sqrt{n}$. Let $A_{s+1}$ be the smallest of the sets $\{i\in A_s: \varepsilon_i=1\}$ and $\{i\in A_s: \varepsilon_i=-1\}$. Remark that $| A_{s+1}|\le |A_s|/2$.
We have $$\|v_s-2v_{s+1}\|=\|v_{s+1}-(v_s- v_{s+1})\|\le \sqrt{n}.$$ Thus

$$\|v_0-2^{s+1}v_{s+1}\|\le \|v_0-2v_1\|+\|2v_1-4v_2\|+\dots +\|2^sv_s-2^{s+1}v_{s+1}\|\le$$ $$\sqrt{n}\left(1+2+\dots +2^s\right)= \sqrt{n}\left(2^{s+1}-1\right).$$

Now pick the smallest $s$ such that $|A_s|\le k$ (so $m/2^{s-1}>k$) and let $\{j_1,\dots, j_k\}\supset A_s$. Then

$$\|v -  v_{\text{proj}}\|\le \|v_0-2^{s}v_{s}\|\le \sqrt{n}\left(2^{s+1}-1\right)>\sqrt{n}\left(\frac {4m}k-1\right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please have a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251105/approximating-the-basis-of-a-specific-function and tell me if my conjecture is right or not. These two questions are very similar